# Simulate clicking button in Lotus-Notes, VBA

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I have an application in Lotus-Notes. I don't have developer rights. My main goal is to automate some process. To do so I need to know how to simulate clicking the button in the view in Lotus-Notes application. I develop it in VBA.

My entry point is to open the view using OpenDatabase method of NotesUIWorkspace:

```
Call notesUIWorkspace.OpenDatabase( server$, file$, view$, key$, newInstance, temp )
```

Now when the view is open I'd like to simulate clicking a button that is on it. Would highly appreciate your help.

BTW I don't want to insert / read documents directly from the database. I need to go through all the process as it is.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What does 'I need to go through all the process as it is' mean?
If you're trying to mimic code that's buried in the Notes app using VBA, you either need someone to share that code with you so you can rewrite it in VBA or you're going to have to reverse engineer the code by trial and error. Without knowing what 'the process' is, it's hard to provide any good help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may run into a number of roadblocks with this approach.  There is no COM method to simulate a button click in Notes.  You might be able to get a handle to the NotesUIDocument and then run a Save action, etc but that won't help if your button does more than that.

I'd check out [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is a Windows keyboard and mouse automation tool.  You could write a script that automates all the actions, perhaps just using keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

In that button, What do you want to execute?

Normally you can not programmatically click the notes action. You can write your codes in Queryopen on all your views.

Otherwise you can create customize Tool bar action, There you can create and compute @Formula into there.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/fram_customize_toolbars_t.html

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply move code from button to library and call function instead of clicking button?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the access to the code. I have very low privilages in that app.

Answer (score 0):

No way through COM, You can approach through the Winapi send message functionality.  Something like below will work, though it is very clunky.  I use this in a few automation projects to simulate clicking notes Buttons.

```
   Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long

' GetWindow() Constants
Public Const GW_HWNDFIRST = 0
Public Const GW_HWNDLAST = 1
Public Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Public Const GW_HWNDPREV = 3
Public Const GW_OWNER = 4
Public Const GW_CHILD = 5
Public Const GW_MAX = 5

'button click constants for SendMessage
Public Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
Public Const WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
Public Const BM_SETSTATE = &HF3
Public Const BM_GETSTATE = &HF2
Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5

Public hwndAction As String
Public hwndClass As String
Public hwndCaption As String
Public hwndHandle As Long

Sub ClickNotes()

hwndAction = "FindHandle"
hwndCaption = "WindowCaption" ''Window Caption here
hwndClass = "NotesSubprog"


FindChildWindows(FindWindow("SWT_Window0", "Windowtitle"))

hwndAction = "FindHandle"
hwndCaption = "WindowCaption"
hwndClass = "NotesSubprog"

FindChildWindows(hwndHandle)


hwndAction = "FindHandle"
hwndCaption = ""
hwndClass = "ActionBar"

FindChildWindows(hwndHandle)

hwndAction = "Click"
hwndCaption = "Comment"
hwndClass = "IRIS.bmpbutton"

FindChildWindows(hwndHandle)

Do While FindWindow("SWT_Window0","New Comment - IBM Notes") = 0
DoEvents
Loop

Wait 3


End Sub

'the method signature is like this only to stay compatible with the Win32 API - lParam will not be used anyway
Function EnumChildWindow(ByVal hChild As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Dim ClassBuffer As String
Dim CaptionBuffer As String
Dim TempVar As Long

ClassBuffer = Space(150)
TempVar = GetClassName(hChild, ClassBuffer, 149)
ClassBuffer = Left(ClassBuffer, TempVar)

CaptionBuffer = Space(250)
TempVar = GetWindowText(hChild, CaptionBuffer, 250)

CaptionBuffer = Left(CaptionBuffer, TempVar)

Debug.Print "Handle: " & hChild & ", Class: " & ClassBuffer & ", Caption: " & CaptionBuffer

If hwndClass = ClassBuffer And hwndCaption = CaptionBuffer Then
Select Case hwndAction
Case "Click"
SendMessage(hChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0)
SendMessage(hChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0)
SendMessage(hChild, BM_SETSTATE, 1, 0)
Case "FindHandle"
hwndHandle = hChild
End Select

Exit Function

End If

'Continue enumeration by recursion
EnumChildWindow = True

End Function

Function FindChildWindows(ByVal hParent As Long)

Dim hChild As Long
Dim Continue As Boolean

Continue = True
hChild = GetWindow(hParent, GW_CHILD)
Continue = EnumChildWindow(hParent, 0)

While Not hChild = 0 And Continue

If Continue Then Continue = FindChildWindows(hChild)
hChild = GetWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT)

Wend

FindChildWindows = Continue

End Function
```